# What's wrong with this makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am new to makefiles. I have a makefile, I want it generated a shared library from more than one .cpp files. But the following makefile only generated different .so based on the same .cpp file. Can anyone help?

```
    SRC_DIR = $(PROJECT_BASE_DIR)/src

    SRCFILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
    OBJFILES = $(patsubst     $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(BUILD_TARGET_DIR)/%.$(OBJ_EXTENSION),$(SRCFILES))

    ...

    ifeq ($(OS),$(OS_LINUX))
    $(CLIENTLIB): $(OBJFILES)
       gcc $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LINKER_FLAGS)

    $(OBJFILES): $(SRCFILES)           ==> I believe this is the line with problem.
       gcc $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're trying to convert all .cpp files to all .o files in one compilation step.

Change:

```
$(OBJFILES): $(SRCFILES)           ==> I believe this is the line with problem.
   gcc $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

to:

```
%.$(OBJ_EXTENSION): %.cpp
   gcc $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. I am getting following error:[exec] gmake: *** No rule to make target `../build_Debug/SampleAuthenticator.o', needed by `libMyPlugIn.so'. Stop

Comment: I just made it work by providing right path... Thanks once more!

Answer (score 0):

These are the rules I use in my makefile and they work, hope it can help you

```
CFILES      = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS        = $(CFILES:%.c=%.o)
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```